# Google Cloud CPU usage to high when sending API requests

Tags: google-cloud-platform, wordpress, google-compute-engine

I have a WordPress site hosted on Google cloud and I'm only using the rest API to GET data and POST data. The only thing I noticed when sending 15 / 20 API calls in a short time was that it crashed the server.

The machine type I'm using is: e2-small (shared server)
CPU platform: Intel Broadwell
GPUs: none

CPU usage most of the time is around 10%. But when sending 20 API calls after each other it spikes up to 170% CPU usage. I can upgrade the CPU, but I don't think this will solve the problem entirely since I may have more traffic in the feature.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your issue as the information provided is not clear.

Comment: Yes, I will. After some investigating, I found the problem. I'll post the solution soon and update my question.

Comment: @ Niels Has your issue been resolved?If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it?